# Not able to access javascript variable(bpath) in php

Tags: javascript, php

I want to access a javascript variable in PHP. My code is looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function update_download(bp)
  {
    var bpath=bp;
    alert(bpath); //working
    <?php
      include("dbconnect.php");
      $sql="select downloads from book_info where book_path='".$bpath."'";
      //code continues.....
    ?>
  }
</script>
```

I need to do some manipulation in database based on the bpath variable, so how can I access it?

Comment: use ajax to send variable to php

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in the way you are trying it.

The JavaScript code is executed on the Client (Browser) while the PHP code runs on your Server (Webspace/Hosting). One cannot pass variable from JavaScript to PHP this way.

The server executes the PHP code and generates a HTML page out of the result (=the stuff not included in PHP tags as well as everything you output/print within your PHP script). So this output contains the JavaScript code as it is not included in the PHP tags, but not the PHP code as this was executed on the server.

To send values from JavaScript you have to use other techniques e.g. a from or an AJAX call.